# How to setup Thinkpad features on Thinkpad T500

Tags: printing, thinkpad, cpu-load, lenovo, hard-drive

I have a IBM-Lenovo Thinkpad T500.  I was previously a exclusive windows user, but recently installed ubuntu and loving it because of speed and interface.  The only thing is that I don't get some features that I came to enjoy in windows.  I need help setting these up:

1. Hard-drive protection - active protection software that pauses drive when there is movement
2. My printer doesn't work (can't find the driver for this one):  canon Ip2600
3. A way to change which graphics chip to use while in OS.  I have both the integrated and non integrated (dual-graphics).  (If not easy to setup, I know there's a way to do it before it boots, but don't know how).
4. CPU performance level - in windows you can pick "high performance", "power saver", etc.. to save batteries.
5. My integrated camera w/light - it works but need an app where I can record videos, take snapshots, etc.  can't find one that works.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to ask ubuntu! The system works best when you split up your questions into individual ones (which also helps you find duplicates) that way we can tackle each one seperately; can you edit your question and file new ones too? Thanks!

Comment: Some of these are really interesting questions, it would be really good if you could reask them in a split up form!

Answer (score 5):

Funny how this question forced me to tweak my own T510

(1) It's called hdapsd and is a simple apt-get install away.
http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/HDAPS

it has an indirect dependacy, tp-smapi-dkms

```
$sudo apt-get install -y tp-smapi-dkms
$sudo modprobe hdaps
$sudo apt-get install -y hdapsd
```

dmesg output

```
[264835.195114] thinkpad_ec: thinkpad_ec 0.40 loaded.
[264835.197174] hdaps: initial mode latch is 0x05
[264835.197319] hdaps: setting ec_rate=250, filter_order=2
[264835.197541] hdaps: device successfully initialized.
[264835.197609] input: ThinkPad HDAPS joystick emulation as /devices/virtual/input/input19
[264835.197746] input: ThinkPad HDAPS accelerometer data as /devices/virtual/input/input20
[264835.197815] hdaps: driver successfully loaded.
```

There be an accelerometer there!

**UPDATE**: I've since found this driver to be a high interrupt consumer
and a real time sink for power efficiency. I no longer run it.

(3) The feature you're looking for is called "switchable graphics"
and it's still under heavy development, likely not ready for an end user.

http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Switchable_Graphics

(5) A easy CLI way to proof this is (sub /dev/videoN accordingly):

```
streamer -c /dev/video0 -b 16 -o outfile.jpeg && gfvs-open outfile.jpeg
```

cheese will also work, it's not the most elegant thing in the world
but it should suffice. I also use my webcam with skype without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I would attempt to answer some of your questions.

2.Look here for your printer drivers

http://software.canon-europe.com/products/0010550.asp

4.You can use the cpu governor gnome-panel plugin to control performance level. Right click on the panel,select "add to panel" and select " Cpu Performance scaling monitor".

5.Have you tried Cheese webcam software. works really well on my ideapad z560.

Answer (score 0):

Super old thread but in case someone stumbles across this in need of help for #2 (printing).
I have a canon printer that is no longer supported by canon (i.e. I can't download drivers to get the printer to work on my mac for example). I did notice I could use gutenprint on my T500 with Ubuntu 20.04 on it. So I set up a print server with a pi3 (pi zero w is probably enough but not very sure) and installed gutenprint on the pi.
HTH!